# Spring MVC 4 - UTF-8 Character Encoding Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, encoding, utf-8

Despite I defined character encoding filters, I'm facing with UTF-8 character encoding errors.

Here is my Spring UTF-8 encoding filter:

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Additionally, I defined my own encoding filter and added it into web.xml

**CharsetEncodingFilter.java**

```
public class CharsetEncodingFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
//        servletRequest.setAttribute("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        String clientEncoding=servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();

        String fileEncoding=System.getProperty("file.encoding");
        if (fileEncoding==null || !fileEncoding.equals("UTF-8"))// eclipse says it's already UTF-8
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");    // so this never gets executed

//        if(null == clientEncoding)    // this is always null
             servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");// so this is always set

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

When I enter `kabakuş` as search query, I got it in controller as it is attached. So hibernate query does not return any results.

[image]

```
Spring version: 4.0.3

Hibernate version: 4.1.1.Final
```

Comment: Where is the query? In the body or in the URL?

Comment: query is created by using `Hibernate Criteria API`. `Hibernate: /* criteria query */ select * from user where (lower(this_.name) like ? or lower(this_.surname) like ?) order by this_.request_date desc limit ?
binding parameter [1] as [CLOB] - %kabakuå%`

Comment: No, I mean where do you retrieve it from the request? In the controller? Where does it come from?

Comment: it comes from request as RequestParam. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: In your request, is the parameter as part of the URL or part of the request body which is `application/x-www-form-url-encoded`?

Comment: it is a part of URL; comes from an AJAX request..

Comment: Check the duplicate. Let us know if there are still problems after.

Comment: ok thanks a lot.. voted up your previous answer. @SotiriosDelimanolis